# Is this just a generic B737 or does it have a specific name?

Tags: boeing-737, aircraft-identification

[image: 737]

Is this just a generic B737 or does it have a specific name?

Answer (score 6):

[image]
([planespotters.net](https://www.planespotters.net/photo/774923/a6-fzz-dubai-air-wing-royal-flight-boeing-737-8knwl))

This is the [A6-FZZ Dubai Royal Air Wing Boeing 737-8KN(WL)](https://www.planespotters.net/airframe/Boeing/737/A6-FZZ-Dubai-Air-Wing-Royal-Flight/Nb0ehO52). The other 737-800's they have have different liveries, namely cheatlines.

Comment: But does it have a name?

Comment: @Notts90 - nope, and I think OP was referring to the reg.

Comment: well all aircraft have a reg don’t they? I thought they meant name like “Air Force One” or “Spirit of Great Britain” etc. or maybe does the model have a nickname like military aircraft do? Maybe I’m overthinking things lol

Comment: @Notts90 “Air Force One” is not a name. I mean, it's *a* name, but it doesn't refer to one, single, specific aircraft. If the president was to fly on a Cessna 172 that aircraft would use the callsign "Air Force One": `Air Force One is the official air traffic control call sign for a United States Air Force aircraft carrying the President of the United States` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_One

Comment: @DeepSpace I'm aware AF1 is the name given to whatever aircraft is carrying the POTUS. It appears this aircraft is used for transporting royals so I don't think it's unreasonable for it to have a name of a similar fashion when carrying certain royals.

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48946/15982