# Do any other nations have an equivalent of the "Air Force One" call sign?

Tags: air-traffic-control, call-sign, air-force-one, head-of-state-transport

> Air Force One is the official air traffic control call sign for a United States Air Force aircraft carrying the President of the United States. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_One)

Do any other nations have an equivalent call sign for an aircraft carrying their head of state?

Comment: I think many countries do, but most probably treat it as a military secret for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is all in your link (in the "See Also"), E.g.:

- Brazil: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_Air_Force_One
- France: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotam_001
- India: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_India_One
- Japan: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_Air_Force_One
- Vatican: "Shepherd One", or just in Italy "Volo Papale #" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_transports_of_heads_of_state_and_government)

Note: Often it is better to disguise who the airplane is transporting (especially when flying above a lot of different countries), and often the president has not so much power ("[nuclear football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_football)"), so a hired jet it is enough, no need to communicate home.